# Resetting Django Form

Tags: python, django, django-views

When the user submits the registration form, I want the page to be refreshed. And the form to be empty. In the past I have achieved this with code similar to the following -

```
form=RegisterForm()
```

But on this occasion, the username and email fields are not being reset. I think I could achieve my objective with AJAX but I am baffled why a solution that has worked previously is not working now.

```
def register_page(request):
form=RegisterForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
context = {
    "form": form
}
if form.is_valid():
    username  = form.cleaned_data.get("full_name")
    emailbatman  = form.cleaned_data.get("email")
    profilepictureironman = form.cleaned_data.get("profilepicture")
    thanospassword  = form.cleaned_data.get("password2")
    new_user  = User.objectsbatman.create_user(username, emailbatman, thanospassword, profilepictureironman)

form=RegisterForm()
return render(request, "accounts/register.html", context)
```

**Before I press submit**

[image]

**After I press submit**

[image]

Comment: You've only changed the `form` variable - `context` still holds the previous version with the Posted form data

Comment: It's also not clear why you want your user, after registering, to see a blank version of the same registration form. It's normal to direct the user elsewhere after successful submission (see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. It worked. 

You made a valid point about redirecting the user elsewhere. I will explore that further.